# Checking registered email and mobile in database using PHP and SQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have this PHP code, which registers a user. All form validation is done by jQuery and the request is sent by Ajax to this PHP page. Everything is working fine except it’s not checking if email and mobile is already registered.

```
<?php
    require('db_connection.php');
    $error = "";
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $hashed_password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT `user_email`, `user_mobile` FROM `users` where `user_email` = ? && `user_mobile` = ? LIMIT 1");
        $stmt->bind_param("si", $email, $mobile);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        if($stmt->num_rows() > 0){
            $row = $stmt->fetch();
            if($email == isset ($row['user_email'])){
                echo "email exists";
            }
            if($mobile == isset($row['user_mobile'])){
                echo "mobile exists";
            }
        }else{
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `users`(`user_name`, `user_email`, `user_mobile`, `user_password`) values (?, ?, ?, ?)");
            $stmt->bind_param("ssis", $name, $email, $mobile, $hashed_password);
            $stmt->execute();
            echo "successfull";
        }
        $stmt->close();
    }
    $conn->close();
?>
```

from my observation the problem is somewhere I'm fetching the rows, because the registration is happening with different email and mobile.

Comment: You probably want `WHERE user_email = ? OR user_mobile = ?`, or just use UNIQUE constraints on those columns. Also, storing phone numbers as integers will usually come back to bite you when you need to preserve leading zeroes or include symbols. Or if you _are_ storing it as a string, then casting it as an integer in the bind might be the problem here.

Comment: ya I was thinking to store as string only. let me try using OR I'll see what happens, also i can use UNIQUE constraints but I want to do it with my code.

Comment: If you implement data constraints only in your code, then you have to remember them _every_ time you write code that interacts with that data, and forgetting about them just once can introduce invalid/corrupt data. Applying the constraints in the database ensures that they are _always_ followed and reduces your code's complexity.

Comment: Yes I will do that but right now i want to know why my code is not working